# Use Elements of Array as Input for Class which needs a String

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a class from [URLEmbeddedView](https://github.com/szk-atmosphere/URLEmbeddedView) which performs an operation on a given String. However I'm trying to use this `class` for a bunch of Strings after each other, and not just one. I prepared an `Array` of `String`, and now I want to perform this class on each element of an `Array`.

The code:

```
var linkArray = [String]() //Contains bunch of Elements

OGDataProvider.sharedInstance.fetchOGData(urlString: TheUrlString) { [weak self] ogData, error in
            if let _ = error {
                return
            }

            let pageTitle = ogData.pageTitle
            Cell.titleLabel.text = pageTitle
}
```

So instead of `TheUrlString` I want to have my array, as I need the pageTitle for each element in that array. How can I accomplish this? Is it possible to use an if which loops through every element?

Comment: if you edit fetchOGData to get table of strings and all other logic you can do that

Comment: You cannot pass  array of urlString if argument accept a String, not unless you have source code which you can alter. You can use `for-in` loop to initialise multiple async operation to download data. If you want dependency or ability to cancel, than `NSOperationQueue` can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
func fetchTitleOGData(index: Int) {
    if (index < linkArray.count) {
         OGDataProvider.sharedInstance.fetchOGData(urlString: linkArray[index]) { [weak self]     ogData, error in
             if let _ = error {
                  //Try again to fetch title
                  fetchTitleOGData(index)
             }
             else {
                 titleArr.append(ogData.pageTitle)
                 fetchTitleOGData(index + 1)
             }
         }
    }
    else {
         //All the title set do what you want.
    }
}
```

Now call this function like

```
self.fetchTitleOGData(0)
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to me like the approach I wanted. Editing the git source isn't that handy.

Comment: But this function will takes time to execute all the url. so better to call this in background with dispatch.